# Как убрать значки остановок общественного транспорта в MapView Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, android, google-maps-api, java

Доброго времени суток!
Использую в приложении **MapView** и на карте есть значки остановок общественного транспорта, можно ли их каким-то образом убрать?
Гугление ничего не дало :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они являются частью карты, ни к одному из дополнительных слоев не принадлежат

UPD: наврал несчадно, посмотрите [здесь](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#styling_the_default_map)
Как я понял, надо создать стиль для карты, в котором элементу transit.station.bus надо поставить visibility off. К сожалению, сам попробовать прямо сейчас не могу.

Comment: я подозревал это, но все такие решил уточнить, спасибо :)

Comment: см. UPD, хотя там вроде только про js api, в андроидовских это может еще не реализовано